# Slicing a dataframe that matches multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to slice up a data frame that returns the column TrueHit in Ascending order on Columns where the yearID is 2010 and G is greater than 100. My code all works except its not matching creating a subset of 2010 and 130 its doing the operation on the whole dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maniac73/Baseball/master/Truehit.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)df.query('yearID == 2010 and G > 100')
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.sort_values('TrueHit', ascending=False)
```

**sample output below**

```
playerID    yearID  stint   teamID  lgID    G   AB  R   H   2B  3B  HR  RBI SB  CS  BB  SO  IBB HBP SH  SF  GIDP    1B  TrueHit
66039   66039   perrypa02   1988    2   CHN NL  35  1   1   1   0   0   1   2.0 0.0 0.0 0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0   5.0
87039   87039   rogered01   2005    1   BAL AL  8   1   4   1   0   0   1   2.0 0.0 2.0 0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0   5.0
78779   78779   motagu01    1999    1   MON NL  51  1   1   1   0   0   1   3.0 0.0 0.0 0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0   5.0
90648   90648   hernafe02   2008    1   SEA AL  31  1   1   1   0   0   1   4.0 0.0 0.0 0   0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0   5.0
61956   61956   quirkja01   1984    2   CLE AL  1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1.0 0.0 0.0 0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0   5.0
```

Comment: Is that the current or the expected output? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe like so?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maniac73/Baseball/master/Truehit.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.sort_values('TrueHit', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df[(df["yearID"] == 2010) & (df["G"] > 100)]
```

output:

```
    Unnamed: 0  playerID    yearID  stint   teamID  lgID    G   AB  R   H   2B  3B  HR  RBI SB  CS  BB  SO  IBB HBP SH  SF  GIDP    1B  TrueHit
94089   94089   thomeji01   2010    1   MIN AL  108 276 48  78  16  2   25  59.0    0.0 0.0 60  82.0    4.0 2.0 0.0 2.0 8.0 35  1.358696
94148   94148   vottojo01   2010    1   CIN NL  150 547 106 177 36  2   37  113.0   16.0    5.0 91  125.0   8.0 7.0 0.0 3.0 11.0    102 1.248629
93202   93202   dunnad01    2010    1   WAS NL  158 558 85  145 36  2   38  103.0   0.0 1.0 77  199.0   10.0    9.0 0.0 4.0 10.0    69  1.222222
93145   93145   custja01    2010    1   OAK AL  112 349 50  95  19  0   13  52.0    2.0 2.0 68  127.0   0.0 5.0 0.0 3.0 6.0 63  1.214900
```